# Output formatting in R

Tags: r, dataframe, export

I am new to R and trying to do some correlation analysis on multiple sets of data.  I am able to do the analysis, but I am trying to figure out how I can output the results of my data.  I'd like to have output like the following:

```
 NAME,COR1,COR2
 ....,....,....
 ....,....,....
```

If I could write such a file to output, then I can post process it as needed.  My processing script looks like this:

```
run_analysis <- function(logfile, name)
{
  preds <- read.table(logfile, header=T, sep=",")

  # do something with the data: create some_col, another_col, etc.

  result1 <- cor(some_col, another_col)
  result1 <- cor(some_col2, another_col2)

  # somehow output name,result1,result2 to a CSV file
 }

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
date <- args[1]
basepath <- args[2]
logbase <- paste(basepath, date, sep="/")
logfile_pattern <- paste( "*", date, "csv", sep=".")
logfiles <- list.files(path=logbase, pattern=logfile_pattern)

for (f in logfiles) {
  name = unlist(strsplit(f,"\\."))[1]
  logfile = paste(logbase, f, sep="/")
  run_analysis(logfile, name)
}
```

Is there an easy way to create a blank data frame and then add data to it, row by row?

Comment: For your last (apparently completely separate) question, look at `rbind`. See the last example on `help(data.frame)`. It is one of the most time inefficient strategies, so don't expect it to scale well once you get beyond the R-newbie stage.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it.  I don't need this to scale very well for now, but it is good to know how I can do it the the right way for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the functions in R for writing data to files? For instance, `write.csv`. Perhaps something like this:

```
rs <- data.frame(name = name, COR1 = result1, COR2 = result2)
write.csv(rs,"path/to/file",append = TRUE,...)
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar (write.csv did not like append=TRUE): write.table(result, output_path, append=TRUE, quote=FALSE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

I like using the foreach library for this sort of thing:

```
library(foreach)

run_analysis <- function(logfile, name) {
  preds <- read.table(logfile, header=T, sep=",")
  # do something with the data: create some_col, another_col, etc.
  result1 <- cor(some_col, another_col)
  result2 <- cor(some_col2, another_col2)

  # Return one row of results.
  data.frame(name=name, cor1=result1, cor2=result2)
}

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
date <- args[1]
basepath <- args[2]
logbase <- paste(basepath, date, sep="/")
logfile_pattern <- paste( "*", date, "csv", sep=".")
logfiles <- list.files(path=logbase, pattern=logfile_pattern)

## Collect results from run_analysis into a table, by rows.
dat <- foreach (f=logfiles, .combine="rbind") %do% {
  name = unlist(strsplit(f,"\\."))[1]
  logfile = paste(logbase, f, sep="/")
  run_analysis(logfile, name)
}

## Write output.
write.csv(dat, "output.dat", quote=FALSE)
```

What this does is to generate one row of output on each call to `run_analysis`, binding them into a single table called `dat` (the `.combine="rbind"` part of the call to `foreach` causes `r`ow `bind`ing).  Then you can just use `write.csv` to get the output you want.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I am going to look at refactoring the script to take advantage of rbind and this foreach library!